# i can't show a net graph by tensorboardX, when i want to do this

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

this code is simple

if **name** == "**main**":
# pass
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

```
model = get_net(False)
input_ = torch.randn((1, 3, 256, 256))
gt_ = torch.rand((1, 2, 256, 256))
# 添加模型结构到TensorBoard
with SummaryWriter(comment="YOLOP") as w:
    w.add_graph(model, (input_,))
```

when i run this ,it fails to show the net graph and make the error as below:

```
          [[ 3.6462e-02,  1.6451e-04,  2.8460e-02, -2.8415e-03, -3.7653e+00,
             4.1301e+00],
           [ 3.6462e-02,  1.6451e-04,  2.8460e-02, -2.8415e-03, -3.7653e+00,
             4.1301e+00],
           [ 3.6462e-02,  1.6451e-04,  2.8460e-02, -2.8415e-03, -3.7653e+00,
             4.1301e+00],
           ...,
           [ 3.6462e-02,  1.6451e-04,  2.8460e-02, -2.8415e-03, -3.7653e+00,
             4.1301e+00],
           [ 3.6462e-02,  1.6451e-04,  2.8460e-02, -2.8415e-03, -3.7653e+00,
             4.1301e+00],
           [ 3.6462e-02,  1.6451e-04,  2.8460e-02, -2.8415e-03, -3.7653e+00,
             4.1301e+00]]]]], grad_fn=<CloneBackward0>)]), tensor([[[[0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          ...,
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000]],

         [[0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          ...,
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000]]]],
       grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>), tensor([[[[0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          ...,
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000]],

         [[0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          ...,
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
          [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000,  ..., 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000]]]],
       grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)]
:List inputs to traced functions must have consistent element type. Found Tuple[Tensor, List[Tensor]] and Tensor
```

i really want to know how to solve the problem,i'm so sad!everytime i run this code,i can't see anything and the tensorboard didn't show any graph,this make me confused,please anyone who can save me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem showed itself in the error log: you have inconsistent data types between input data and tensors.
The first solution I come up with is fixed data type for both, like this:

```
input_ = torch.randn((1, 3, 256, 256), dtype=torch.float32)

model = model.to(dtype=torch.float32)
```

Comment: thank you ,i try to change the code ,but it still fails.the error shows:      
RuntimeError: Tracer cannot infer type of [(tensor([[[1.7871e+00, 1.8513e+00, 4.2458e+00, 1.1566e+01, 3.1512e-04,
          9.8259e-01],
         [5.7871e+00, 1.8513e+00, 4.2458e+00, 1.1566e+01, 3.1512e-04,
          9.8259e-01],
         [9.7871e+00, 1.8513e+00, 4.2458e+00, 1.1566e+01, 3.1512e-04,
          9.8259e-01],